# Check if "make install" was called

Tags: cmake

I have a make test that depends on make install. (I know that no the wa it is supposed to work). However is there an official way to check if make install was called at test runtime?

My google foo didn't help me.

Only way I could think of was setting some cache variable during install time and check this at test time.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to run `make install` (or equivalent) as part of the test?

Comment: No, what I really want to to is: "show some sort of warning/message if make test is called before make install

Comment: "*I know that is not the way it is supposed to work*" -- Personally, I would work on making that dependency go away, instead of working around the problem; so you can `make test` *before* `make install` the way it *should* be. Problem solved. ;-)

Comment: Sure, sadly that is not an option (right now)

Answer (score 0):

> Only way I could think of was setting some cache variable during install time and check this at test time.

I am quite sure cache variables are not available during the run of `make install`, doubly so for writing.

Depending on why exactly you want this check, it should be enough to test the existence of an installed file:

```
# Let us assume your CMakeList installs a file to a/b.fil

add_test(
  NAME theTestInQuestion
  COMMAND ... # as usual
)

set_property(
  TEST theTestInQuestion
  PROPERTY REQUIRED_FILES ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/a/b.fil
)
```

See documentation of [`REQUIRED_FILES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/REQUIRED_FILES.html) test property for details.